# get a specific link of downloaded google search site

Tags: httpclient, webclient

I want to do the following in C#:

1. load website in background (google search site)
2. look into the sourcecode of this site and get a specific link

I tried this before:

1. Use the `WebClient` Class to download the String of the website

```html
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string reply = client.DownloadString(url);
client.DownloadFile(gesamter_String, @"C:\neu\localfile.html");
Console.WriteLine(reply);
```

2. Use the `HTTPClient` Class to download the String of the website

```html
string url = hyperlink;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)
   {
     using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
     {
      string result =content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    
       Console.WriteLine(result);
     }
  }
```

But the downloaded or displayed sourcecode is very small and doesn't contain the specific link.

However my links works. I have opened the link in foreground with this: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);`. This foreground opened site contains the full sourcecode.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is actually a violation of Google's Terms of Use, so my professional answer is to not do this. Personally, I have tried to accomplish this before and ran into several blocks (including IP address blocking) that Google has in place to prevent you from spidering or screen-capturing their search results. The reasons they block it should be obvious. If you are doing this just for fun or some personal training exercise, I'd recommend some other site that won't try to block you.

Comment: The official way to invoke google search from c# is https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client . Trying to scrape the site is usually not worth the bother and as mentioned, may get you blocked.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanations. I tried different search sites and Bing seems to work so far.